# Is it plausible to plug in equations for series in python?

Tags: python, graphing, exponential

I am trying to make an exponential function based on atmospheric pressure and height using python. i somehow have to be able to make the equation `y = ( 1000 * e**( (-9.81 x / ( 78351 ) )` into a graph.

where **`y`** = 0 - 15 and **`x`** = 1000 y

while i could have python calculate each individual one, the point of the exercise is to be able to use the equation above as means for the graph.

**Is there a way that i can have:**

```
y_series = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...]
```

and

```
x_series = [1000 * e**( -9.81 ( y_series ) / 78351 ) ?
```

I've tried multiple ways but keep getting : x and y must have same first dimension error.

Comment: Instead of describing your code that isn't working and the error you're getting, _show_ us your code, and the error. (If the code is more than a few lines long, show us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the same problem instead). We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: ah, sorry i'm new to programming!this is my most recent attempt: y_series = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]             x_series = [1000*2.718**((-9.81*1000*y)/(273*287)) for y in y_series] (im now getting a syntax error)

Comment: my other attempt was to go about it the long way such as this: y_series = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] X_series = [1000*2.718**((-9.81*0)/(273*287)),1000*2.718**((-9.81*1000)/(273*287)),etc this lead to the y and x must have same first dimension

Comment: Don't try to write code in comments. First, formatting in comments is horrible. Second, the information needs to be in the question, so people can search for the question, decide whether they want to look at it, answer it, etc., all of which don't see comments. Read the help; it really is helpful. Meanwhile, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is:**

**Syntax scheme:**

```
e        = 2.71                                                   # SET e
y_series = range( 0, 16 )                                         # GEN y_series
x_series = [ 1000 * e**( -9.81 * y / 78351 ) for y in y_series ]  # GEN x_series
```

**Output:**

```
>>> x_series
[1000.0, 999.8751840341362, 999.7503836472979, 999.6255988375402, 999.5008296029192,
999.3760759414907, 999.251337851311, 999.1266153304365, 999.0019083769238,
998.87721698883, 998.7525411642123, 998.6278809011279, 998.5032361976348,
998.3786070517907, 998.2539934616539, 998.1293954252827]
```